# Autoincrement a string's last integer value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using vb.net and reading a string from mysql database. Now the string contains `"test 1"`. I want to increment the last digit (1) by the value 1. I somehow used string length and solved it but it works only for string up to `"test 10"` and then it keeps adding spaces for example: `"test    13"` and so on. I want to just have strings auto incremented like `"test 20"` or `"test 100"`. How can I do so?

This is the code I am using:

```
If reader2.Read Then
    var = reader2.GetInt64("version")
    a = reader2.GetString("project_id")
    location = reader2.GetString("location")
    governorate = reader2.GetString("governorate")
    memo = reader2.GetString("memo")
    title = reader2.GetString("project_title")

    var = var + 1
    Dim st As String
    st = a.Substring(0, a.Length - 2)

    st = st & " " & var

    b = st
```

b should have the value of "test 2" or the incremented final value

Comment: Is `version` always the number at the end of `project_id`? I recommend to use more meaningful variable names than `var` for `version`, `a` for `project_id` and `st` for whatever that variable is.

Comment: yes version is the end. i will definitely change variable names, thanks for the headsup :) . But how shall i increment the value? the spaces are being added as soon as the number increases more than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your case projected is “description value” then it is easily done with split function like below:

```
var = var + 1
Dim st As String
st = a.Split(" ")(0)
st = st & " " & var

b = st
```

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that you are using `Substring(0, a.Length - 2)` where `2` is a constant value which never increases even if the number of digits increases.

If there is a space between the project-name and the number you can use `String.Split` instead:

```
Dim version = reader2.GetInt64("version")
Dim projectID = reader2.GetString("project_id")
Dim token As String() = projectID.Split() ' splits by white-space characters '
Dim projectName As String = token(0).Trim()
Dim result As String = String.Format("{0} {1}", projectName, version + 1)
```

If you want to use `Substring` instead of `Split`:

```
' ... '
Dim projectName = projectID
Dim spaceIndex As Int32 = projectName.IndexOf(" ")
If spaceIndex >= 0 Then projectName = projectName.Substring(0, spaceIndex)
' ... '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i have tried both the methods, they are working great cheers :)